# Offset compared to Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Macro and want to reduce the number of lines to speed up the process.

```
5
ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
If Selection.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
GoTo 6
End If

Selection.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
GoTo 5
```

I want to replace multiple the **'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight'** lines with a single line using Offset.

Can you please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your x5 `Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight` by `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)).Insert shift:=xlToRight`

**EDIT**

More related to your code: `Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 4)).Insert shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: This is perfect.  
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 4)).Insert shift:=xlToRight
Was the right code for my Macro.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Could you please mark the answer as accepted so others know the question has been answered? Thanks.